# How can I close a streamSubscription from a different class

Tags: flutter, dart, location

I have 3 different classes, one a global class, another `class1` and the other `class2`. In global class, I have global variables of two streamsubscription for locations.

```
StreamSubscription<Location> rideStreamSubscription;
StreamSubscription<Location> backgroundSubscription;
```

in `class1` I have this method which calls to initiate the stream.

```
void getLocationLiveUpdates() async {
await BackgroundLocation.startLocationService();
    backgroundSubscription = BackgroundLocation.getLocationUpdates((location) {
/////
}
  }
```

Which works fine, Now when I go to `class2` I want to close `backgroundSubscription` stream and start `rideStreamSubscription`

```
void getRideLocationLiveUpdates() async {
    await backgroundSubscription.cancel();
    await BackgroundLocation.stopLocationService();
    await BackgroundLocation.startLocationService();
    rideStreamSubscription= BackgroundLocation.getLocationUpdates((location) {
/////
}
  }
```

but I get this error

```
 [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'cancel' was called on null.
```

My questions are is there any other way to do this? If I don't close the first stream then I get an error

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

but it doesn't show where is it coming from.
I am using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/background_location) library

Comment: You're calling `backgroundSubscription.cancel()` before `backgroundSubscription` has been initialized.  Use `backgroundSubscription?.cancel()` to do nothing if `backgroundSubscription` is `null`, or explicitly check if it's `null` first.

Comment: @jamesdlin I've already initialized `backgroundSubscription` in `class1`  `backgroundSubscription = BackgroundLocation.getLocationUpdates((location) {
}` When I move on to `class2` I want to close it and start `rideStreamSubscription`.  Thank you, I will do the null check. .Apologies if my question wasn't clear. Ive updated it.

Comment: You have code to initialize it, but you aren't guaranteeing that that code is executed (and completes) before `getRideLocationLiveUpdates` is called.  The error clearly indicates that `getRideLocationLiveUpdates` is called while `backgroundSubscription` is still `null`, so you must check.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is totally OK, but problem is that you trying to cancel your subscription before start listening.

Solution:
just add a null check:
`await backgroundSubscription.cancel();`
(or move cancellation to `stopListening` with null check)